# Copying elements from parameter list into a calling object?

Tags: c++, linked-list

Given a non-empty singly-linked list, the function copies all elements from the parameter list into the calling object.

```
void AnyList::preFour(const AnyList& otherList) {

    bool found = false;

    Node* checkPtr = otherList.ptrToFirst;

    //find first 4
    while (checkPtr != nullptr && !found) {

        if (checkPtr->getData() == 4) {
            found = true;
        }
        else 
            checkPtr = checkPtr->getPtrToNext();
    }


    Node* current = ptrToFirst;
    Node* copy = otherList.ptrToFirst;

    while (current != checkPtr) {


        current = current->getPtrToNext();
        copy = copy->getPtrToNext();
    }
}
```

This is the code I have so far, I just need some pointers on how to copy the parameter list to a certain extent while copying those elements into the calling object (empty list). Would I need to create a new Node?

Comment: The parameter object would be: 1,2,3,4 => The calling object would be 1,2,3

Comment: I suggest you shift your focus to `STL containers`. Plenty of goodies there.

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
void AnyList::preFour(const AnyList& otherList) {

    bool found = false;

    Node* checkPtr = otherList.ptrToFirst;

    //find first 4
    while (checkPtr != nullptr && !found) {

        if (checkPtr->getData() == 4) {
            found = true;
        }
        else 
            checkPtr = checkPtr->getPtrToNext();
    }

    Node* current;
    Node* copy = otherList.ptrToFirst;


    /* This node is just to facilitate in copying. 
       It actually stores no relevant data. 
       It will be deleted after we are done with copying.*/
    Node* dummy = new Node(); 
    current = dummy;

    while (copy != checkPtr) {

        Node* temp = new Node();
        current->next = temp; // Use appropriate method to set nextptr
        current = current->getPtrToNext();

        *current = *copy; // Use appropriate copy constructor or other method
        copy = copy->getPtrToNext();
    }
    /* This method should return NULL if next pointer is not available.
       If that is not so, just add a check here. 
    */
    ptrToFirst = dummy->getPtrToNext();
    delete dummy;
}
```

Since the calling object's list is empty, we first need to allocate space for first node. So I create a `dummy` node first:

```
    Node* dummy = new Node();
    current = dummy;
```

And while we don't reach the stopping condition, we keep copying contents from parameter list to calling object's list using this loop. We have to create a new node every time the condition succeeds. This is because we have to allocate space for copying new elements.:

```
    while (copy != checkPtr) {

        Node* temp = new Node();
        current->next = temp; // Use appropriate method to set nextptr
        current = current->getPtrToNext();

        *current = *copy; // Use appropriate copy constructor or other method
        copy = copy->getPtrToNext();
    }
```

Note that after copying I assign `ptrToFirst` to be `dummy->getPtrToNext()` and then `delete` the `dummy` node.

Comment: Can you explain everything after Node* current?